# jquery: не срабатывает событие для изображения

Tags: jquery, события

есть такая конструкция

```
<div class = 'box'>
    <div class = 'object'>
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Для изображения создал такой обработчик:

```
$('.object img').on('error', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/empty.png');
});
```

Но когда пытаюсь сделать такой обработчик, завязав его на `.box`

```
$('.box').on('error', '.object img', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/empty.png');
});
```

ничего не срабатывает

**В чем может быть дело?**

Когда делаю аналогичное для событие 'click' всё срабатывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие [`error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) не всплывает.

Так как в случае `$('.box').on('error'` обработчик вешается непосредственно на элемент с классом `box`, событие произошедшее в `img` теряется.

Comment: т.е. никак не обойти?

Comment: @Zhihar, навешивать на картинку непосредственно

Comment: тогда надо будет заморачиваться с удалением события при удалении картинки, а когда я навешиваю на `.box` меня вообще не волнует удалялись или создавались изображения

Comment: на самом деле не надо будет.